# "Proper" way to design history log

Tags: database-design

Currently, I have an entity **Ticket**, now I plan to create another entity called **TicketHistory** just as the image shown below to track the changes that happened to **Ticket** entity, I wonder if this is the "proper" way to design this case ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, looks fine.

These kind of history tables are sometimes referred to as temporal tables or temporal data. In fact, some database systems have this as a feature built in, to automatically manage tracking of data changes.

This will vary depending on your database system, but in Microsoft SQL Server these are some of the main data change tracking features available:

1. [Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16)
2. [Change Data Capture (CDC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)
3. [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)
4. [Ledger Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/ledger/ledger-overview?view=sql-server-ver16)